# Adding AutoLayout Constraints To A UITableView When Adding To Parent View

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am trying to create the following setup with Autolayout to my UITableView before I add it as a subview of its wrapper UIView.

[image]

I am using the following so far but haven't had any luck at all. This is as far as I have got and it is throwing an errors.

```
//Trailing
    NSLayoutConstraint *trailing =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:self.tableViewVideoList
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self.viewContentWrapper
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                   constant:0.f];

    //Leading

    NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:self.tableViewVideoList
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self.viewContentWrapper
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                   constant:0.f];

    //Bottom
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottom =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                 constraintWithItem:self.tableViewVideoList
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self.viewContentWrapper
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                 multiplier:1.0f
                                 constant:0.f];

    [self.viewContentWrapper addConstraint:trailing];
    [self.viewContentWrapper addConstraint:bottom];
    [self.viewContentWrapper addConstraint:leading];


    [self.viewContentWrapper addSubview:self.tableViewVideoList];
```

Any help would be great thanks, I usually do all the Autolayout work in the Storybaord.

Comment: What are the errors you are facing?

Comment: You need to add the table view as a subview before adding pinning constraints

Comment: I think you also need to set the height of tableview either by adding the top constraint or explicitly setting the height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to do this:

```
self.tableViewVideoList.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

And you should add `tableViewVideoList' to its superview before setting the constraints.

And you are missing a top layout constraint or height constraint (as 3stud1ant3  pointed out)